# Serialize class with list to url string and pass via MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I have question it is possible serialize class with list to url string and after that pass to MVC controller action with some additional parameters like this `public ActionResult Index(int? SomeId, Class Class)`?

```
public class Class
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Serialize this class to url:**

```
var classToSerialize = new Class()
{
    Id = 1,
    Items = new List<Item>()
    {
        new Item() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1"},
        new Item() {Id = 2, Name = "Name2"}
    }
};
```

How url must looks like?

Comment: URL is not the best option to pass complex values as it is has length limit. You should use `POST` method and put your serialized class in the request body.

Comment: Thanks for your comment you get another point of view how it possible to implement my app

Comment: POSTing this data back would be better.

Comment: `../Index?Id=1&Items[0].Id=1&Items[0].Name=abc&Items[1].Id=2&Items[1].Name=def`. But do not do this - you will likely exceed the query string limit and throw an exception - post the data instead

Comment: Thanks, I understand that it is not good idea:)